# Get localhost project name from url

Tags: php, codeigniter

If I have a url like `http://localhost/project1/` How am I able to get the project1 name from url

What I am trying to achieve is if is localhost `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . $project`

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && (($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == '1'))) {
echo 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
} elseif ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost') {
echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/'; // GET PROJECT NAME Place after .'/'.
} else {
echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using `APPPATH . 'config/constants.php'` for such a need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the requested URI with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

So to get the project name in your URL you could do :

```
$project = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1];
```

To get the the full host or your project you could do :

```
function getFullHost()
{
    $protocole = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'].'://';
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
    $project = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1];
    return $protocole . $host . $project;
}
```

Comment: For some reason that just echos out 'localhost' but not project name

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve the parts of an URL with the `parse_url()` function:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/project1/';
$parts = parse_url($url);
print_r($parts);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => localhost
    [path] => /project1/
)
```

Or, if you want to get the path directly:

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
// => /project1/
```

Comment: Is there away not have to hard code url like so `$url = 'http://localhost/project1/';`

Comment: You could try using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'`] and apply the `parse_url()` function to it. But to be honest, it's been ages since I used a raw `$_SERVER` variable :) - as you are using CodeIgniter, isn't there an URL helper you could make use of?

Answer (score 0):

Better way if you have more than one sub directories:

```
function getFullHost()
{
    $protocole = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'].'://';
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
    $project = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    array_pop($project);
    array_shift($project);
    $path = implode('/', $project);
    return $protocole . $host . $path;
}
```